# Let $f(x)$ be defined over all rationals $x$ in $[0,1]$ and let $F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(\frac in)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, power-series

also define $$F^*(n) = \sum_{i=1\,\,(i,n)=1}^n f(\frac in)$$ then prove that $$F^* = \mu * F$$
where $\mu$ is the Möebius function and the $*$ means the Dirichlet convolution.

I tried the Bell series which gave me this:

$$F^*(p^k) = \sum_{i=1}^{p^k} f(\frac i {p^k}) - \sum_{i=1}^k f(\frac{p^i}{p^k})$$
$$F^*(p^k) = F(p^k) - \sum_{i=1}^k f(\frac{p^i}{p^k})$$
(assuming $k\geq1$ and $p$ an arbitrary prime)

$$x^kF^*(p^k) = x^kF(p^k) - x^k\sum_{i=1}^k f(\frac{p^i}{p^k})$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}x^kF^*(p^k) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}x^kF(p^k) - \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(x^k\sum_{i=1}^k f(\frac{p^i}{p^k}))$$

because $$F(1) = F^*(1)$$ we have

$$h_p(F*) = h_p(F) - \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(x^k\sum_{i=1}^k f(\frac{p^i}{p^k}))$$

where $h_p(f)$ represents the bell series of $f$ with respect the prime $p$
all I need to prove is that

$$xh_p(F) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(x^k\sum_{i=1}^k f(\frac{p^i}{p^k})) $$
which is equivalent to 
$$h_p(F) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(x^{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^k f(\frac{p^i}{p^k})) $$

or if you will:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} x^k \sum_{i=1}^{p^k}f(\frac i{p^k}) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(x^{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^k f(\frac{p^i}{p^k})) $$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} x^k \sum_{i=1}^{p^k}f(\frac i{p^k}) = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(x^{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} f(\frac{p^i}{p^{k+1}})) $$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} f(\frac{p^i}{p^{k+1}})) =  \sum_{i=1}^{p^k}f(\frac i{p^k})$$

it seems to me that the sum in the right contains more terms than the sum in the left (and also contains the whole sum of the left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a standard derivation of the result. To help us in the derivation we start by introducing the $\delta$-function $\delta_{m,n}:\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q} \to \{0,1\}$ by $$\delta_{m,n} = \left\{\matrix{1 & m=n\\0 & m\not= n}\right.$$  By construction, the $\delta$-function satisfy the following identity:

> Identity 1: If $d\mid n$ and $i\leq n/d$ then $\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_{i,j/d}h(j) = h(id)$ for any function $h$.

Another useful identity is the [Möbius function sum property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function#Properties_and_applications) in the following form:

> Identity 2: $\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\sum_{i=1}^{n/d}\delta_{i,j/d} = 1$ if $(n,j)= 1$ and $0$ otherwise.

This follows by writing out
  $$\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\sum_{i=1}^{n/d}\delta_{i,j/d} = \sum_{d\mid n,\,d\mid j}\mu(d) = \sum_{d\mid (n,j)}\mu(d) = \delta_{(n,j),\, 1}$$

Using the two identities above the derivation is pretty straight forward:
$$
\begin{align}(\mu * F)(n) &\equiv \sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\sum_{i=1}^{n/d}f(id/n) \\&= \sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\sum_{i=1}^{n/d}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\delta_{i,j/d}\,f(j/n)}~~~~~~~\text{(using identity 1)}\\&= \sum_{j=1}^{n}f(j/n){\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\sum_{i=1}^{n/d}\delta_{i,j/d}} ~~~~~~~\text{(switched the summation order)}\\&= \sum_{j=1,\,(n,j)=1}^nf(j/n)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{(using identity 2)}
\end{align}
$$